# How can I get rid of the reflection spots?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have these iris images and I want get rid of the reflection spots. Are there any suggestions? I don't want to set their pixels values to zero. I'd like them to be normal as their neighborhood pixels. Thank you in advance.

An example image:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`roifill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html) function

```
img = imread('https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/31683/51-7.bmp'); 

sp = img > 240; %// find the bright spots, use some high threshold
J = roifill( img, imdilate( sp, ones(5) ) ); %// replace the bright spots
```

And you get (original on the left, `J` on the right):

[image]

---

According to [kkuilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503560/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-reflection-spots/30504514?noredirect=1#comment49086884_30504514), [`roifill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html) is not supported for recent Matlab versions, and [`regionfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionfill.html) should be used instead:

```
J = regionfill( img, imdilate( sp, ones( 5 ) ) );
```

Comment: For information... [roifill](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html) is not recommended as of R2015a. Use [regionfill](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionfill.html) instead.

Comment: @kkuilla thanks for this point. I updated my answer accordingly.